# Expressão regular para ignorar separador entre aspas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

Tenho que ler uma arquivo csv com delimitador `;`.

Só que tem linhas com os valores `"""Analize;Distribuição"""`, só que ele cria uma outra coluna neste `;`. Como consigo ler para ele não aceitar `;` dentro de aspas como delimitador?

Exempro de uma linha:

```
105;3650;Fernando;"""Analize;Distribuição""";0;Finalizado
```

O resultado gerado é:

```
105
3650
Fernando
"""Analize
Distribuição"""
0
Finalizado
```

Gostaria que fosse:

```
105
3650
Fernando
"""Analize;Distribuição"""
0
Finalizado
```

Comment: quer substituir o `;` por `,`, é isso?

Comment: Sim, é que no caso e csv esta sepado por ``` ;```, e tem um valor escrito ```"""um texto qualquer; outro texto qualtquer"""```. E acontece que ele reconhece esse ; como um delimitador tambem e acaba criando  uma coluna a mais. Estava vendo e tem jeitos de não trocar o valor do ```;```e alterar o logica do ```split()```, porém ainda não consigo resolver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Provavelmente uma biblioteca específica para CSV seja o mais indicado, já que bibliotecas dedicadas costumam tratar esses casos especiais de uma maneira melhor do que regex, mas de qualquer forma, segue uma sugestão.*</sup>

---

Você pode usar esta regex:

```
var pattern = "\"{3}\\w+;\\w+\"{3}|[^;]+";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches("105;3650;Fernando;\"\"\"Analize;Distribuição\"\"\";0;Finalizado", pattern);
Console.WriteLine("{0} campos encontrados", matches.Count);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0]);
}
```

Ela usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`), que significa "ou". Ou seja, a regex tem duas possibilidades:

1. `\"{3}\\w+;\\w+\"{3}`: 3 aspas, seguida de `\w+` (um ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos), seguido de `;`, `\w+` e mais 3 aspas
2. `[^;]+`: um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `;`

Note que usei `+` em vez de `*`. O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` garante que deve haver pelo menos um caractere, já o `*` admite zero caracteres (ajuste conforme sua necessidade).

A regex tenta primeiro verificar se tem o caso com aspas, e se não der, a alternância tenta a segunda opção (`[^;]+`).

Depois, basta percorrer os *matches* para obter os respectivos trechos.

A saída é:

```
6 campos encontrados
105
3650
Fernando
"""Analize;Distribuição"""
0
Finalizado
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que sejam 2 problemas, o primeiro seria substituir `;` por `,`, isso pode ser resolvido com um `texto.Replace(";", ",");`. O outro seria retornar essas ocorrências, nesse caso ficaria mais ou menos assim

```cs
    var texto = "asfdgsdfgsdfg\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"fawsgasdfasdfasd\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"sadfgsdfgsdfg\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"fasdfasdfasdfasdf\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"sadf";
    var pattern = @"""""""\w*;\w*""""""";
    var linhas = Regex.Matches(texto,pattern);
    System.Console.WriteLine(linhas.Count);
```

Quando tiver problemas com regex vc pode usar o [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) ele funciona bem para .net, uma vez que aparentemente as implementações de regex em linguagens diferem entre si.

Caso queira substituir o `;` pelo `,` em cada uma das ocorrencias, vc pode usar algo nesse sentido

```cs
    var texto = "asfdgsdfgsdfg\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"fawsgasdfasdfasd\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"sadfgsdfgsdfg\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"fasdfasdfasdfasdf\"\"\"texto;texto\"\"\"sadf";
    var pattern = @"""""""\w*;\w*""""""";
    var textoModificado = Regex.Replace(texto, pattern,
    encontrato =>
    {
        return encontrato.Value.Replace(";", ",");
    });
    System.Console.WriteLine(texto);
    System.Console.WriteLine(textoModificado);
```

Comment: Jose Paulo, eu editei a pergunta agora estava meio sem sentido, da uma olhada e veja se tem alguma solução para ajudar. Obrigado

Comment: Dei uma editada na resposta veja se ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Gente consegui resolver com o código abaixo

```cs
// mangled code horribly to fit without scrolling
public static class CsvSplitter
{
    public static string[] SplitWithQualifier(this string text,
                                              char delimiter,
                                              char qualifier,
                                              bool stripQualifierFromResult)
    {
        string pattern = string.Format(
            @"{0}(?=(?:[^{1}]*{1}[^{1}]*{1})*(?![^{1}]*{1}))",
            Regex.Escape(delimiter.ToString()),
            Regex.Escape(qualifier.ToString())
        );

        string[] split = Regex.Split(text, pattern);

        if (stripQualifierFromResult)
            return split.Select(s => s.Trim().Trim(qualifier)).ToArray();
        else
            return split;
    }
}
```

[Pergunta respondida aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807536/split-string-in-c-sharp)